# Know when new HTML elements are fully loaded with .load()

Tags: jquery, load

i have some problems with `.load()` jquery function, i'm tring to pre load some HTML in a hidden block than when all new elements are loaded i want move it in the dom tree.
that is my script

```
var preloader = $(document.createElement("div")).attr('id', 'msgloader').css({ visibility: "visible"}); // visible is just for test it 
preloader.html( newHtml ); // newHtml is a string with html elements like images table etc.
$("body").append(preloader);
preloader.load(function() { alert("div is ready"); });
```

i don't know why but when the new HTML in msgloader is ready and fully loaded never trigger `alert()` message do you know where i make miskate?

Comment: `preloader.html( newHtml );` after that line, the elements will be available. There is not need to listen to an event.

Answer (score 2):

Any reason why you wouldn't just do this in document ready?  Since you're modifying the dom directly, your changes should be available immediately, so load() never fires because it's being set up after you've already added the code.

Answer (score 0):

`.load()` is for loading data from a server. When you just `.append()` some HTML, it is ready immediately. Your `load()` function doesn't show an alert because it isn't `load`ing anything.

Answer (score 0):

See the caveats for the [load method](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
>   shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
>   images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
>   this that should be noted. These are:
>
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> - Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

It's not a particularly reliable way of determining when all content of an element has finished loading. You may consider using the [overloaded load method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load your html from an url, and adding to the DOM once that load is complete (or alternatively, just add to the DOM on DOM ready).